# School timetabling with Optapy - allow to choose teacher from a list for a lesson

Tags: python, optapy

I am trying to use Optapy with the school timetabling example as a base.
For any given of subject I have a list of teachers that potentially can teach this subject and each teacher can potentially teach 1 to 3 subjects. I want to optimize the teacher allocation to the lessons, such that, each student group can only have one teacher for any given subject and each student group supposed to get few lessons for any subject (i.e. 4 times math lesson for the student group A given by teacher B)

For that I tried to the add this problem fact:

```
@problem_fact
class Teacher:
    def __init__(self, id, name, subject, subject2, subject3):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.subject = subject
        self.subject2 = subject2
        self.subject3 = subject3

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return (
                f"Teacher("
                f"id={self.id}, "
                f"name={self.name}, "
                f"subject={self.subject}, "
                f"subject2={self.subject2}, "
                f"subject3={self.subject3})"
        )
```

and I added planning variable to the planning entity:

```
@planning_variable(Teacher, ["teacherRange"])
def get_teacher(self):
    return self.teacher

def set_teacher(self, new_teacher):
    self.teacher = new_teacher
```

But I don’t know how to continue make the algorithm to chose a teacher from a list and  how to add the constraints of one teacher for one student group for any subject. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the algorithm to chose a teacher from a list, the list must be returned from a method on the `@planning_solution` class annotated with the appropriate `@value_range_provider`:

```
@planning_solution
class TimeTable:
    def __init__(self, teacher_list, ..., score=None):
        self.teacher_list = teacher_list
        # ...
        self.score = score

    @problem_fact_collection_property(Teacher)
    @value_range_provider("teacherRange")
    def get_teacher_list(self):
        return self.teacher_list
    # rest of the class
```

For the constraint "one teacher for one student group for any subject.", I would rephrase it "consistent teacher for subject on student group" (i.e. if a lesson has the same student group and subject, it must also have the same teacher). Which would be written like this:

```
def consistent_teacher_for_subject_and_student_group(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return constraint_factory \
        .forEach(LessonClass) \
        .join(LessonClass,
              [
                  # ... the same student group ...
                  Joiners.equal(lambda lesson: lesson.student_group),
                  # ... the same subject ...
                  Joiners.equal(lambda lesson: lesson.subject),
                  # form unique pairs
                  Joiners.lessThan(lambda lesson: lesson.id)
              ]) \
        .filter(lambda lesson1, lesson2: lesson1.teacher != lesson2.teacher) \
        .penalize("Different teacher for the same student group and subject", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
```

For the constraint "teacher must be able to teach subject", you can use a filter:

```
def teacher_must_be_able_to_teach_subject(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return constraint_factory \
        .forEach(LessonClass) \
        .filter(lambda lesson: lesson.subject not in {lesson.teacher.subject, lesson.teacher.subject2, lesson.teacher.subject3}) \
        .penalize("Teacher cannot teach subject", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
```

Comment: I am not sure how to define the teacher_list in this way. I defined the teacher_list and the lesson_list like that:
lesson_list = [
        Lesson(1, "Math", "9th grade"),
        Lesson(2, "Math", "9th grade"),
        Lesson(3, "Physics", "9th grade"),
...
]

teacher_list = [
        Teacher(1, "A. Turing", "Math", "English", "French"),
        Teacher(2, "M. Curie", "Chemistry", "English", "French"),
        Teacher(3, "C. Darwin", "Spanish", "History", "Biology"),
...
    ]
But how do I link the subject attribute of the teacher to the subject attribute of the lesson?

Comment: I added an example of linking the subject attribute of the lesson to the teacher. For future flexibility, I recommend using a list or a set to store the subjects a Teacher can teach (so an attribute subject_list) rather than having separate attributes subject1, subject2, subject3. That will change the filter in the example to `lambda lesson: lesson.subject not in lesson.teacher.subject_list`

Comment: I added the constraint 'teacher_must_be_able_to_teach_subject' to the constraint_provider but it gives me an error when I ran the solver: "An error occurred during solving. This can occur when functions take the wrong number of parameters (ex: a setter that does not take exactly one parameter) or by a function returning an incompatible return type (ex: returning a str in a filter, which expects a bool). This can also occur when an exception is raised when evaluating constraints/getters/setters."  I checked the setter that takes one parameter and the filter in constraint gives returns a boolean

Comment: That is a generic error message since I cannot extract any additional information when a TypeError is raised. As such, generic advice is given with examples. I edited the answer (added missing backslash for line continuation, removed comment which broke line continuation). Try the changes. If the exception happens again, is there another exception above it?

Comment: Yes, I get few exceptions: org.jpype.PyExceptionProxy followed by java.lang.RuntimeException, Java Exception, org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.ConstraintEvaluationException, RuntimeError. I used the edited code but still getting the same exceptions.

Comment: I think I see the issue; I used `teacher.subject1` instead of `teacher.subject`. I tested these constraints locally, so I know they work (provided the model matches).

Comment: Perfect, that worked